# Geocoding by route number and distance

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, linear-referencing

How can one get coordinates from input consisting of country, route number and distance from the beginning of the route?

For example: (Austria, A1, 0 km), (Belgium, A12, 20 km) etc.

I have looked at multiple geocoding APIs and none of them offers such funcionality.

I have found a partial solution for some cases. Sometimes wikipedia page of the route contains a google maps route under External links. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A2_road_(Latvia) (see extarnal links at the bottom)

Comment: I think this is not a geocoding question, rather a routing question which can be solved by means of GIS. IMHO the main issue for you is the data. Do you know sources where you may find all highways with corresponding route numbers and required attributes? Besides how will you define *"the beginning of the route"*? Based on the example that you provided, is Riga a starting point or Veclaicene?

Comment: @Taras Thank you for your response. These routes have a defined starting and end point. The Latvian example was not the best one, if you look at Austrian routes [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobahns_of_Austria) you can see clearly stated sequence of points. If you click on any particular route it will even state 'from' and 'to'. I guess you are right about it not being a geocoding question as data consisting of country, route number and start/end coordinates would solve my problem.

Comment: Google maps, OSM etc. all have these route numbers shown when you zoom on a particular road. Google geocoding API even returns a route object by using route name as input. However, this object does not have start and end point coordiantes as attributes. It returns center and corner coordinates of rectangle enclosing the route. I asked it as a geocoding question hoping that another geocoding api could return start and end point of these routes.